# Stucked Threads with Apache HTTP Client 4.5.x

Tags: java, network-programming, apache-httpclient-4.x

in my weblogic a lot of threads are stuck on this way, but I can't figure the reason. This is the stacktrace. I setted all timeouts of the connection:

- setConnectionRequestTimeout
- setConnectTimeout
- setSocketTimeout

This is the stack trace, I don't see any problems with code (at the end of post) that can cause this stucks threads. Any idea about this?

```
<22-May-2018 11.48.46 CEST> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000337> <[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '36' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "616" seconds working on the request "Http Request Information: weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl@7567f23c[POST /aca/rest/servicesupport]
", which is more than the configured time (StuckThreadMaxTime) of "600" seconds in "server-failure-trigger". Stack trace:
    java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
    org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
    org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:282)
    org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
    org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
    org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
    org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:165)
    org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.createTunnelToTarget(MainClientExec.java:473)
    org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:398)
    org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    com.iberia.es.integration.FacadeSFIntegrationImpl.requestToken(FacadeSFIntegrationImpl.java:71)
```

This is the Class with the connection methods. I am using **Apache http client 4.5.3**:

```
public class FacadeSFIntegrationImpl implements FacadeSFIntegration {


    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("confResolver")
    ConfigurationResolver config;

    @Override
    public String requestToken(List<IbEsNameAndValueDTO> params, String url, Boolean proxyEnabled,
            Integer connectionRequestTimeout, Integer connectTimeout, Integer socketTimeout) {

        if (params != null && !params.isEmpty() && url != null) {

            try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
                // Preparamos los parámetros
                List<NameValuePair> httpParams = convertParams(params);

                // Configuramos la llamada
                RequestConfig httpConfig = configHttpRequest(proxyEnabled, connectionRequestTimeout, connectTimeout,
                        socketTimeout);

                // Realizamos la llamada post
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
                post.setConfig(httpConfig);
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(httpParams, "UTF-8"));

                // Controlamos la respuesta
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (status >= 200 && status < 300) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    return EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                }

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                //LOG
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                //LOG
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //LOG
            }
        }

        return null;
    }


    private RequestConfig configHttpRequest(Boolean proxyEnabled, Integer connectionRequestTimeout,
            Integer connectTimeout, Integer socketTimeout) {

        Builder httpConfigBuilder = RequestConfig.custom();

        if (proxyEnabled) {
            String proxyUrl = config.getValue("proxy.host");
            String proxyPort = config.getValue("proxy.puerto");

            HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyUrl, Integer.valueOf(proxyPort));
            httpConfigBuilder.setProxy(proxy);
        }

        String connectionRequestTimeoutDefaultS = config.getValue("proxy.timeout.connectionRequest");
        httpConfigBuilder.setConnectionRequestTimeout((connectionRequestTimeout != null) ? connectionRequestTimeout
                : Integer.valueOf(connectionRequestTimeoutDefaultS));

        String connectTimeoutDefaultS = config.getValue("proxy.timeout.connect");
        httpConfigBuilder.setConnectTimeout((connectTimeout != null) ? connectTimeout : Integer
                .valueOf(connectTimeoutDefaultS));

        String socketTimeoutDefaultS = config.getValue("proxy.timeout.socket");
        httpConfigBuilder.setSocketTimeout((socketTimeout != null) ? socketTimeout : Integer
                .valueOf(socketTimeoutDefaultS));

        return httpConfigBuilder.build();
    }

    private List<NameValuePair> convertParams(List<IbEsNameAndValueDTO> params) {

        List<NameValuePair> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (IbEsNameAndValueDTO nameValue : params) {
            result.add(new BasicNameValuePair(nameValue.getName(), nameValue.getValue()));
        }
        return result;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request execution got stuck while establishing a tunnel to the target via a proxy. Please note that request level socket timeout setting applies to fully established connections only. In order to avoid such situations you might want to set default timeout to a positive value on the connection manager level with [SocketConfig](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.4.x/current/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/config/SocketConfig.html) using [#setDefaultSocketConfig](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/current/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html#setDefaultSocketConfig(org.apache.http.config.SocketConfig)) method of the client builder or directly on the connection manager

```
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setConnectTimeout(5000)
        .setSocketTimeout(5000)
        .build();
SocketConfig socketConfig = SocketConfig.custom()
        .setSoTimeout(5000)
        .build();
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
        .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
        .setDefaultSocketConfig(socketConfig)
        .build();
```

Comment: Can you help me with an example? I don't know how implement this SocketConfig in my code

Comment: Thanks, I don't know this timeout, I hope this doesn't make more problems :)

Comment: hi @ok2c I am facing the same issue I think. I do not understand the solution here completely. Can you elaborate please!